# How to convert this using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
l = []
for i in range(11):
    l.append(1)
    for j in range(i):
        l.append(0)

print(l)
```

The output follows a `(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...)` pattern. I do not know however how to convert nested-for loops using list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

This is tricky to write as a comprehension because of the need to add two separate elements in each iteration. It can be implemented using a list `sum`:

```
l = sum([[1] + [0] * i for i in range(11)], [])
```

Output:

```
[
 1,
 1, 0,
 1, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
l = [0 if j else 1 for i in range(11) for j in range(i+1)]
```

or in a slightly shorter albeit more obfuscated form:

```
l = [int(not j) for i in range(11) for j in range(i+1)]
```

Comment: I like this, the iteration of `j` over `range(i+1)` and testing the `j` value to generate the list value is a nice trick.